# How to upgrade Internet Explorer 8 to Internet Explorer 9 or later?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer

I really need an Internet Explorer 9 or later because it is necessary for a data connection from Google Sheets to my Excel File. I have tried many options but all are not working.

My operating system and updates that I have tried are shown below:
[image]

My `About Internet Explorer 8` details:
[image]

1st: I used MS Excel's notification link to download what I believe should upgrade to IE 10.

[image]

But I think I was wrong and it was an update for IE 10. However, in the 6 options in that web page, none was an installer for anything except for Windows 8 for Vista operating systems as shown in #3 in the image.

[image: Selection]

2nd: Look for automatic updates in `About Internet Explorer 8` but then there is no checkbox as other web pages say.

3rd: I tried to download a IE 11 offline installer for Windows 7 SP1 32-bit which is my operating system, but it says I should have a Windows 7 SP1.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried installing the service pack that the installer is asking for?

Comment: The "build number" for SP1 is 7601, you have 7600 which is the original version of Windows 7 without the service pack. Download and install Windows 7 SP1: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/15090/windows-7-install-service-pack-1-sp1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I really need an Internet Explorer 9 or later because it is necessary for a data connection from Google Sheets to my Excel File. I have tried many options but all are not working.

In order to install IE 10 or IE 11 on Windows 7 you  **must** install Service Pack 1.  You currently do not have it installed.  If you do not have Service Pack 1 installed it means you are also vulnerable to numerous SMBv1 vulnerabilities.

You should patch your system immediately.  Google Sheets only supports the current build of IE11 on Windows 7 by the way.

[Install Windows 7 Service Pack 1 (SP1)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/15090/windows-7-install-service-pack-1-sp1)

Answer (score 1):

The default Internet Explorer on Windows 7 SP1 is IE 11. So what we need to do is install Windows 7 SP1 at first. 
Try to download it from the link below:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/15090/windows-7-install-service-pack-1-sp1
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The last version of Internet Explorer to run on Windows 7 RTM is IE9, the SP1 requirement checks were implemented starting with IE10 during pre-Windows 8.0 era.

[Overview Of Internet Explorer 9 On Windows 7 Build 7600](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d314D.png)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) as well as other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also [tour] for the site tour, and [help] for the help center.